# reading strings and numbers from input file stream using getline

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I get the syntax for `getline(ifstream foo, string bar)` function and I know its third parameter which is delimiter, is set to '\n'.

I have a file to read, and it has numbers on first and second column.
The problem is that on the third column, I have to read names of countries which may have contain spaces.

I've checked my code is successfully reading numbers from first two columns for sure, but as my code tries to read the country name , I get a `'Segmentation fault (cord dumped)'` error message.

My code looks like this:

```
string name[50];
double year1[50],year2[50];
fstream ifstr;
ifstr.open("thefile.csv");
for (int i=0; (!(ifstr.eof())) || i < 51; i++) {
ifstr >> year1[i] >> year2[i];
getline(ifstr, name[i]);} // expecting this line to be reading/storing
//anything that comes after 3rd column into string array
```

The given variable for my assignment is way too long and complicated, so I kind of wrote that up to help readability, but that one line is pretty much the problem.

From the instruction sheet, my professor mentioned

> Reading the populations is straightforward, and can be done using the
>   standard file IO functions we covered in class (i.e., ">>" using an
>   input stream). However, since the names of some countries contain
>   spaces, we need to use getline instead of >> for the name field.
>   Fortunately, the country is the final field so we can use ">>" to read
>   the populations and then a getline to finish the line.
>       You will need to input data until the end of file is reached. Recall that getline's return value is false if at end of file, so its
>   easy to check for this.

I looked up all sources available regarding this topic, but I couldn't find one that solves this so far.

Please advise.

Comment: You have a combination of the [`while(!eof)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) antipattern, and reading out of bounds (e.g. accessing `year1[50]` is undefined behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop condition is wrong.  You should only loop while *both* of those values are true.  If either one of them becomes false, you should stop.  So the `||` should actually be `&&`.

You also have an out-of-range problem.  The condition `i < 51` is wrong.  A value of 50 for `i` will overflow your arrays when you index them.  So the correct condition is `i < 50`.

Finally, `eof` is not the only condition on a stream that should cause you to stop reading.  Just use the bool operator of the stream.

```
for( int i = 0; ifstr && i < 50; i++ )
```

Comment: Thank you for your correction. Still after the fix, Segmentation fault persist. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Compile your program with debug symbols enabled (`-g` flag).  Attach a debugger such as `gdb` and run your program.  Let it crash, and use `bt` debugger command to show you the call stack.  That will tell you which line of code caused the problem.

Comment: File can be compiled /run without problem without the line that has `getline`

Comment: What I exactly wish to know is that how to read/store 1st and 2nd column into `int` variable and 3rd and 4th (possibly 5th, even 6th) columns as a `string ` variable, using
`ifsream ifstr >> year1[i] >> year2[i]; // for int variables` and `getline //for the rest of columns as a string variable`